# Como integrar um sistema Java com um em COBOL?

Tags: java, web-service, cobol

Quais as opções para um sistema Java se comunicar com um sistema feito em COBOL? É possível o uso de WebServices? Caso não, JCA seria a melhor opção?

Comment: Sim, é possível o uso de web services. Também dá pra usar JCA, também dá pra comunicar via CORBA... A melhor opção é aquela que melhor se adequa à sua necessidade e ambiente, os quais você não descreveu.

Comment: Desde já agradeço a resposta. Bom, eu tenho um sistema em Java que cadastra resultados de exames. Todo exame cadastrado eu preciso notificar um sistema feito em Cobol, que precisa dessas informações para resolver outras regras de negócio. Basicamente é isso. O esquema de filas de mensagens seria o ideal, mas como o sistema é em cobol surgiram as dúvidas de integração.

Comment: Algum problema em consumir filas de mensagens em COBOL? IBM MQ (antigo WebSphere MQ), por exemplo, tem bibliotecas prontas em COBOL para consumo e publicações em filas de mensagens, e existem mais opções.

Comment: Nossa cara. Não sabia disso não. Dei uma pesquisada por alto e não encontrei nada sobre o "IBM MQ" nesse contexto. Valeu demais ;)

Comment: From Wikipedia: "It was originally called MQSeries, and was renamed WebSphere MQ in 2002 to join the suite of WebSphere products. In April 2014, it was renamed IBM MQ. IBM MQ, (often referred to as "MQ"), is IBM's Messaging solution for Enterprise and IBM's Message Oriented Middleware offering."

Comment: Olás! Conhecem alguma solução gratuita?

Comment: Achei este artigo bem bacana: http://www.infoq.com/articles/legacy-integration.